# Save and load JSON and scala's objects on-top/with Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am encountering an issue reading and writing files with spark, to a "remote" file system (such as hadoop).

## Contents

1. What did I do locally?
2. What do I want to do on 'remote'?

### 1. What did I do locally?

As for now, I worked with spark locally - read and wrote files to my device, as follows:

**Spark-Session Initializating**:

```scala
  val spark: SparkSession = Try(
    SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("app")
      .getOrCreate()) match {
    case Success(session)=>session
    case Failure(exception)=> throw new Exception(s"Failed initializing spark, due to: ${exception.getMessage}")
  }
```

**Save/Write locally, and then Load/Read it:**

*(Json File)*

```scala
  val content = "{"a": 10, "b": [], "c": {"x": "1", "z": {}}, {"x": "2", "z": {}}}"  // dummy JSON as string
  val fileName = "full_path/sample.json"

  // ... verify directory exists and create it if not ...

  // write sample.json with the content above:
  new PrintWriter(fileName) {
    write(content)
    close()
  }

  // Read & Operate on it:
  val jsonAsBufferedSource = Source.fromFile(fileName)
```

*(Scala's Case-Class)*

```scala
  case class Dummy(string: String, i: Int) extends Serializable {}
  val content = Dummy("42 is the best number", 42)       // Dummy instance
  val fileName = "full_path/sample.dummy"               // 'dummy' is the serialized saved-object name.
  
  // ... verify directory exists and create it if not ...

  // Write it:
  val output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))
  output.writeObject(content)
  output.close()

  // Read:
  val input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))
  val dummyObject = input.readObject.asInstanceOf[Dummy]
  input.close()

  // Operate:
  dummyObject.i   // 42
```

### 2. What do I want to do on 'remote'?

I want to be able to read/write on HDFS, S3, or any other 'remote' file system that is available outhere, with spark - as I did locally.

**Mostly, the my questions are:**

- **Spark Configurations**: what and how should it be changed? [master, etc..]
- **Working With Spark**:

  - How can I save and load serializable objects, as I did locally?
  - How can I save a Json string, and load it as a BufferedSource?

Generally speaking - I would like to allow myself work locally/remotly with the same "internal-interfaces" of my application.

Thank you for reading!

### EDIT

I would like my app to save/read files to DISK and work above my computer's disk when testing and debugging. I would like it to save/read with a remote file-system when in production. 
 Is it possible using the same spark methods? with what spark-configurations?

**Oren**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question. Spark works with file:// and hdfs:// or s3a:// prefixes all the same. It is Source.fromFile and PrintWriter that are wrong

You'll need to rewrite the functions to use proper Spark methods since Spark is meant to run **in the cluster**, not isolated to one machine (referred to as the driver)

```
// read all JSON files in a folder
val df = spark.read.json("file:///path/to/full_path/")

// write the dataframe to HDFS folder
df.write.format("json").save("hdfs://namenode.fqdn:port/hdfs/path/")
```

Sure, you could serialize a class, write to a file "locally" (which would be "remotely" when `deploy-mode=cluster`), then upload *that*, but that doesn't seem like what you're doing here. And rather than doing that, you would `parellelize` a `Seq` of the serialized object.

Use `json4s` rather than ObjectOutputStream to get JSON from case-classes.

Comment: Thank you!
I will try to be more clear - I want my application to be able to work remotly (in a cluster, that can be hdfs/s3a or whatever), and to work without a cluster, on my device, for "home use".
Until now - I was working with my master as "local[*]" with the methods above, without using spark to read/write (but just to operate on some DFs).

Is there any way to use the same spark methods to read/write files both on my device (locally), and on a remote cluster - only supplying different spark configurations to the system? 
Thank's again!

Comment: As stated, those "local methods" are not Spark methods, and must be changed

Comment: Is it even possible to save/load files (json, serialized case-classes) locally, and act on them on the same way as working on-remote? I turned to use these methods on the first place because spark "didn't want" to save files on device - so I thought just to implement it in 2 ways (for 'local' use, and for 'remote').

Comment: Again, using `file://` prefix operates on local files of the Spark executors

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer. 
Just making sure - using file:// will allow me saving and loading csv/json files ON MY DISK?
I would like my app to work on disk when debugging/testing, and above a cluster in production.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I consier it a solved issue.                 
I used `sparkSession.read.json(fileName)` and `Seq(jsonString).write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(fileName)` for the JSON saving and loading, as well as `sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(myObject),1).saveAsObjectFile(path=fileName)` and `sparkSession.sparkContext.objectFile[DummyObject](fileName).first()` for the object saving and loading.